# Output of below program show A=30, B-30 and C=30 any on can explain why not A=10, B=20 and C=30?

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x
    def show(self):
        print("A:", self.x)


class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 20

    def show(self):
        super().show()
        print("B:", self.x)


class C(B):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 30

    def show(self):
        super().show()
        print("C:", self.x)


obj = C()
obj.show()
```

Tried the code and different cobbination but got answer A=30, B-30 and C=30 Need A=10, B=20 and C=30 in mentioned.

Comment: Your inherited `__init__`s never even get invoked. If they _did_, you'd see whichever value is set last for all three. The only way this would work is if you used `super` (to invoke the parent implementations) and _name mangling_ (i.e. named the attribute `__x`). Even then it's unclear where the 10 would come from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only `C`'s `__init__` method gets invoked, `self.x` is only *ever* set to `30`. Even if you did use `super().__init__()`, each assignment to `x` would overwrite any previous assignment - you'd still end up with one value, which one would depend on the order of the `super` calls vs. assignments. An instance can only have one value for a given attribute name.

If you really do want the different classes to have different values, and assuming that the rest of the public interface is correct, a working implementation would look something like:

```py
class A:

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.__x = x

    def show(self):
        print("A:", self.__x)


class B(A):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(10)
        self.__x = 20

    def show(self):
        super().show()
        print("B:", self.__x)


class C(B):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.__x = 30

    def show(self):
        super().show()
        print("C:", self.__x)
```

Using `__x` as the attribute name invokes *name mangling* (see [Designing for Inheritance](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#designing-for-inheritance)), which means `A` actually has `_A__x`, `B` has `_B__x`, and so on. This is deliberately intended to prevent subclasses overriding the attributes of their superclasses - it's not a good idea generally (it's not the idiomatic way to make "private" attributes, for example), but if you *want* each one to have a separate value this is how you do it. In use:

```
>>> obj = C()
>>> obj.show()
A: 10
B: 20
C: 30
```

However, note that external access to `__x` is also prevented, you have to be specific about *which* `__x`:

```
>>> obj.__x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'C' object has no attribute '__x'
>>> obj._A__x
10
>>> obj._B__x
20
>>> obj._C__x
30
```

Answer (score 2):

There's only one object (which is an instance of `C`), so `x` refers to the same variable in each case. Thus, when you print the value of `x`, it couldn't possibly refer to separate values in the base classes.

Also, as indicated in the comments, the `__init__`s for `B` and `A` are never actually called (and even if they were, you'd just be overwriting the current value of `x` every time, so it would always show the same value).